# Java: How do I get a Scanner object to ignore unwanted/invalid inputs?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to set up a simple text tree that reads in either single-characters (y/n) or integers that correspond to a printed list (1-4). I want to know the easiest way to have the program ignore user inputs that don't correspond to the given options like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class simpleMenu
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choicePick;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (y/n)");
        choicePick = sc.next();

        if(choicePick.equals("y"))
        {
            // The program continues.
        } 
        else if(choicePick.equals("n"))
        { 
            // The program closes.
        } 
        else 
        {
            /* 
            The scanner ignores the input, ideally without having to restate the question.
            The program does not quit or move on until "y" or "n" is entered.
            */ 
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus points if you can help me implement a 'back' option that takes me to the previous choice.

Comment: You don't.  Once you've called `sc.next()`, you've already read the input.

Comment: There is no bonus for you by dropping the learning part on other people.

Comment: This is not a school assignment. I meant bonus appreciation points; it was just an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the next string is not Y or N sc.next() until it is. Then use that string.