# Forbidding program from inputting a number less than 1 (if else / switch)

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

So I'm writing a program that compares box volumes... but I need to make it run so that values less than one are not printed and would prompt an error message. (i.e. "The first box is 0.5 times the size of the second box" or "The first box is 0 times the size of the second box") -- Instead I would like it to print "Error: Please enter a valid number greater than 1"

Here is the part of my code that I am trying to fix:

```
if (volume1 == volume2) {
        System.out.println("The first box is the same size as the second box");
    }else if(volume1 >= 0 || volume2 >= 0){
        System.out.println("Error. Please enter a valid number greater than 0");
    }else {
        String bigger = "first box";
        String smaller = "second box";
        double ratio = volume1 / volume2;
        if (volume2 > volume1) {
            bigger = "second box";
            smaller = "first box";
            ratio = volume2 / volume1;
        }
        String compare;
        switch((int) ratio) {
        case 1: compare = " is slightly bigger than "; 
        break;
        case 2: compare = " is twice the size of "; 
        break;
        case 3: compare = " is triple the size of ";
        break;
        case 4: compare = " is quadruple the size of "; 
        break;
        default: compare = " is " + (int) ratio + " times the size of ";
        break;
        }

        System.out.println("The " + bigger + compare + smaller);
    }
```

I hope this is enough code to explain what my issue is. From what I have learned I don't think switch statements can have conditions, and because of the way the int ratio is structured it keeps printing 0 when I test it. Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How do I get a Scanner object to ignore unwanted/invalid inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663844/java-how-do-i-get-a-scanner-object-to-ignore-unwanted-invalid-inputs)

Comment: `if(volume1 >= 0 || volume2 >= 0)` means that you print `Error. Please enter a valid number greater than 0` any time one of the values is greater than 0. I think you meant `if(volume1 <= 0 || volume2 <= 0)`, or rather `if(volume1 <= 1 || volume2 <= 1)` since you seem to have changed you mind as to the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I hope I did get your question right :)
Well you could just add a little if Statement to the default-branch:

```
// Here the Code till default
default:
    if (ratio < 1) {
        System.err.println("Error: Please enter a valid number greater than 1");
        return; // You should consider to return out of the method here otherwise "The" still gets printed for no reason :)
    } else compare = " is " + (int) ratio + " times the size of ";
}
// Rest of Code
```

This should do the job :)